# How to send and recive curl data [Opencart]

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send some data information from server to localhost but for some reason cant receive the data and I can't understand where is the problem

Code from the server sending

```
$curl = curl_init();

$test = array(
        'name'  => 'xaxa',
        'lname' => 'zzzz'
);
$curl_handle=curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'https://127.0.0.1/stock2/test.php/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($test));
$res = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

json_decode($res, true);
```

Localhost code

```
<?php

$handle = fopen('file.txt', 'w');

if (is_resource($handle)) {
  fwrite($handle, $_GET);
  fwrite($handle, $_POST);
  fwrite($handle, print_r($_FILES, true));
  fwrite($handle, print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], true));
  fclose($handle);
}
```

file.txt is empty at all, where is the problem?

Comment: where is the server in relation to `localhost`?

Comment: @RamRaider what do you mean ?

Comment: well - I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do with sending data from the server ( which server ) to the localhost ( which host, the server? )

Comment: @RamRaider im trying to send array with data information about orders from server machine that is shared hosting to localhost

Comment: `shared hosting` - where? The internet or the machine at which you now sit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201488/discussion-between-ramraider-and-ivan).

Comment: Here is one example sharing data by opencart through API https://webocreation.com/blog/pull-products-json-through-api-opencart/ 
As in the example: the requesting is https://tuliprsdynasty.com/api/apiproducts.php in your case is localhost and responding is https://webocreation.com/nepalbuddha in your case another shared hosting server.

Comment: @RupakNepali i will have a look this one thx